# How to reverse the direction of Array.Sort - C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, sorting

I have a simple string array, with number 1 -  10, that I'm sorting with the following:

```
Array.Sort(StringArray, StringComparer.InvariantCulture);
```

My questions is, how can I change the direction of the sort from 1 - 10 ascending, to be come 10 - 1 descending?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort the numbers in C# using Array methods, try this:

```
int[] arr = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6, 7, 8, 9, 10}; 
Array.Sort(arr); //1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10     

Array.Reverse(arr); //10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options. [Here is the most common I use](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-sort-an-array-in-descending-order-in-c-sharp/).

[Linq over a List can also be used.](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-sorting-operators-orderby-orderbydescending)

```
// C# program sort an array in  
// decreasing order using  
// CompareTo() Method 
using System; 
  
class GFG { 
  
    // Main Method 
    public static void Main() 
    { 
  
        // declaring and initializing the array 
        int[] arr = new int[] {1, 9, 6, 7, 5, 9}; 
  
        // Sort the arr from last to first. 
        // compare every element to each other 
        Array.Sort<int>(arr, new Comparison<int>( 
                  (i1, i2) => i2.CompareTo(i1))); 
  
        // print all element of array 
        foreach(int value in arr) 
        { 
            Console.Write(value + " "); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

or

```
// C# program sort an array in decreasing order 
// using Array.Sort() and Array.Reverse() Method 
using System; 
  
class GFG { 
  
    // Main Method 
    public static void Main() 
    { 
  
        // declaring and initializing the array 
        int[] arr = new int[] {1, 9, 6, 7, 5, 9}; 
  
        // Sort array in ascending order. 
        Array.Sort(arr); 
  
        // reverse array 
        Array.Reverse(arr); 
  
        // print all element of array 
        foreach(int value in arr) 
        { 
            Console.Write(value + " "); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found this ... seems to work great.

```
Array.Reverse(StringArray);
```